# c# wpf Mahapps Tile in code or with Databinding and Custom DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

I try to build tiles dynamically in a Scrollviewer. All Data Comes from a `List<myclass>` that is filled from a webservice.

The DataTemplate should be a grid with two Labels and a Picture I now tried different approaches but it Looks like I don't understand some Basics up to now. Can somebody please help me with providing an example?

Answer (score 0):

`ScrollViewer` is a content control. In order to display a list of items such as tiles you need to use the `ItemsSource` property of an items control such as `ListView` or `ItemsControl`.

In other words you need to bind your List to `ItemsSource` of a `ListView` using `{Binding ...}` syntax and making sure you set the `DataContext` of the View and your list is a part of that `DataContext` class, typically a `ViewModel`.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference and thank you for the tip/help. The following is the solution. I hope it is correct and ok to provide it.

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" x:Name="VisitPlanScrollView" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Margin="20,0,20,0">
            <ItemsControl  Name="VisitPlanItems" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ></StackPanel>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Controls:Tile x:Name="VisitPlanTile" Click="TileClick" >
                            <Controls:Tile.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="Controls:Tile">
                                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"></Setter>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF0068B3"></Setter>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding bIsEmptyPlan}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"></Setter>
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGray"></Setter>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Controls:Tile.Style>
                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>

                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Label  Content="{Binding VisitPlanTitelSub}" Foreground="White" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></Label>
                                <Label   x:Name="ibsSubTitle" Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding VisitPlanID}" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></Label>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                    <Label x:Name="TileDetailCount" Content="{Binding VisitPlanDetailCount}" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ></Label>
                                    <Button x:Name="button_CreatenewReminderVPTile" Click="button_CreatenewReminderVPTile_OnClick" ToolTip="Erstellt eine neue Wiedervorlage zu diesem Besuchsplan." >
                                        <Button.Style>
                                            <Style TargetType="Button">
                                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF0068B3" ></Setter>
                                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF0068B3"></Setter>
                                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF0068B3" ></Setter>
                                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF0068B3"></Setter>
                                                <Style.Triggers>
                                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding bIsEmptyPlan}" Value="True">
                                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGray" ></Setter>
                                                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkGray"></Setter>
                                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGray"></Setter>
                                                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"></Setter>
                                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                </Style.Triggers>
                                            </Style>
                                        </Button.Style>
                                        <iconPacks:PackIconModern Kind="Notification" Foreground="White">
                                            <iconPacks:PackIconModern.Style>
                                                <Style TargetType="iconPacks:PackIconModern">
                                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF0068B3" ></Setter>
                                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF0068B3"></Setter>
                                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding bIsEmptyPlan}" Value="True">
                                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGray" ></Setter>
                                                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkGray"></Setter>
                                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGray"></Setter>
                                                        </DataTrigger>
                                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                                </Style>
                                            </iconPacks:PackIconModern.Style>
                                        </iconPacks:PackIconModern>
                                    </Button>
                                </StackPanel>

                            </Grid>
                        </Controls:Tile>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
```